# Why is the posterior proportional to P(X=x|C=c_i)P(C=c_i)?

Tags: machine-learning

When we are trying to maximum a posterior,we apply Bayesian rule to convert them into posterior probabilities!
[This is most of the textbooks typically claimed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41UR2.png)

how can i be sure that it is really the case?

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com is a better place to ask this question...

Comment: The question is pretty badly specified. Do you mean, how can you be sure the posterior probabilities are really what's being claimed? That's just Bayes theorem. If this isn't what you mean, you should formulate a question more precisely. Also, as Andre mentions, you may find more help for your new, clearer question on the stats exchange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In these cases you are doing

```
argmax_{c_i} p(C=c_i|X=x)
```

which is the most probable class given evidence. Since the x is fixed in this case (the data you are trying to find the best class for) so is P(X=x), it's the probability for the data.